# Describing coordinate surfaces

Tags: coordinate-systems

Some arbitrary coordinate system with components $x'^a$ is related to Cartesian coordinates, $x^a$, by
\begin{align}
x^1 &= x'^1 +x'^2 \\\
x^2 &= x'^1 - x'^2 \\\
x^3 &= 2x'^1x'^2 + x'^3.
\end{align}
What are the coordinate surfaces described by the primed system? I understand that the coordinate surfaces of the Cartesian system are flat planes where one of the coordinates is fixed (e.g. $x=1$). I have rearranged the equations above to give the primed coordinates in terms of Cartesian:
\begin{align}
x'^1 &= \frac{1}{2}(x^1 + x^2) \\
x'^2 &= \frac{1}{2}(x^1 - x^2) \\
x'^3 &= x^3 - \frac{1}{2}\left((x^1)^2 - (x^2)^2\right).
\end{align}
I am struggling to visualise what fixing one of the primed coordinates, say $x'^1$, and letting the others vary would look like. My educated guess would say that they also describe 2D planes, but not mutually orthogonal.